# How to implicitly convert a pointer, to a const pointer, during variadic template deduction

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Imagine the case, where one (for one reason, or another) wanted to implement a function, that acts like a proxy when calling functions. One could implement it as a template, which takes a pointer to a function, and all of its arguments. However, if there is a function, that accepts a `const` pointer to something (e.g. `int const*`), and you are trying to pass just a simple pointer to function (e.g. `int*`), the template deduction fails, due to ambiguous template argument. Example:

```
#include <utility>
template <class... TArgs>
void foo (void (*pFunc)(TArgs...), TArgs... args)
    {
    pFunc (std::forward<TArgs> (args)...);
    }

void bar (int const* pInt) {}

int main ()
    {
    int a = 5;
    foo (bar, &a);
    }
```

Produces:

> error C2672: '`foo`': no matching overloaded function found
>
> error C2782: '`void foo(void (__cdecl *)(TArgs...),TArgs...)`': template parameter '`TArgs`' is ambiguous
>
> note: see declaration of '`foo`'
>
> note: could be '`const int*`'
>
> note: or       '`int*`'

Even if, simply calling `bar (&a)` would succeed due to implicit conversion between `int*`, and `int const*`.

Yes, I realize, that one could specify the argument types directly (e.g. (`foo<int const*> (bar, &a)`), but given the fact, that arbitrary amount of arguments are accepted, such list would be quite long, and, would, in my personal opinion, look ugly.

Another option, would be, to liter the code with `const_cast`s, wherever such conversion would be needed, but that would, also, inflate the code in undesirable ways (or in other words, would look ugly, as well).

The 3rd solution, that I could think of, would be to provide 2 parameter packs, like so:

```
template <class... TArgs, class... TArgs2>
void foo (void (*pFunc)(TArgs...), TArgs2... args)
    {
    pFunc (std::forward<TArgs2> (args)...);
    }
```

Which, would solve the immediate problem of implicit argument conversion, but would introduce another problem, of compiler errors pointing to the `foo` implementation, instead of `foo` invocation, in the case of mismatched arguments to the function, which would make it harder to identify where exactly, in the code base, the mismatched call was being made. Example of errors, that I get, if I use the above example, and the following `main` function:

```
int main ()
    {
    float b = 5;
    foo (bar, &b);
    }
```

> error C2664: '`void (const int *)`': cannot convert argument 1 from '`float *`' to '`const int *`'
>
> note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
>
> note: see reference to function template instantiation '`void foo<const int*,float*>(void (__cdecl *)(const int *),float *)`' being compiled

So, the question is, is there some sort of template magic, that would allow it to work in the manner, that I expect, given the restrictions, and considerations, I have given above? Or am I just being unreasonable with my requirements?

Comment: If you are that paranoid about error messages: `static_assert((std::is_convertible_v<TArgs2, TArgs> && ...));`

Comment: @PasserBy But, wouldn't that, still, provide the error message in a template implementation, opposed to the invocation of such template function?

Comment: Isn't that a bonus? In that you can provide a error message along with it.

Comment: @PasserBy The contents of the error message is not a problem. It states which argument is at fault, and the types of both expected, and actual types. However, the main point of concern is the location of the error. Since, this template would be invoked from multiple places of the code base, it would be hard to find the offending call to such template function.

Comment: "make it harder to identify where exactly, in the code base, the mismatched call was being made" Which compiler do you use? Compilers usually put the whole instantiation chain into the error message. Btw., you need to use `TArgs... &&` to make `std::forward` useful.

Comment: @geza MSVC. I tested, and it doesn't provide the call chain. Let me edit the question, so I could include the errors, that I get in that case.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: maybe you use an old MSVC then. My version does show the whole call chain.

Comment: MSVC 2015 shows the originating call: https://godbolt.org/z/sJsz4z

Comment: @geza I nearly typed the reply, and then noticed something.. It does provide the entire callstack, in the notes, but I failed to notice.. /Facedesk Thank you, for making me look harder..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: great :) Note, I meant `TArgs2... &&` in my previous comment (I cannot edit it now). If you use type deduction, it needs to be an rvalue reference, so `std::forward` can do its work properly.

Comment: @geza Well, rvalue reference doesn't improve the behavior, since it works in the similar manner, as plain `TArgs2...`, as far as I have observed.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Without `&&`, a deduced type will never be a reference. So, there is no point using `forward`, as it will always mean `move`.

Comment: @geza Hmm.. Maybe, given the answer to my question, I'll try it out, once again. Since, why I didn't think of using it, was the issue (with my initial implementation), where, there were ambiguous call errors where it couldn't decide if the type was `int*`, or `int*&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could constrain the function:

```
template <class... TArgs, class... TArgs2>
enable_if_t<is_invocable_v<void(TArgs...),TArgs2...>>
foo (void (*pFunc)(TArgs...), TArgs2... args)
    {
    pFunc (forward<TArgs2> (args)...);
    }
```